# Webcam installation problem in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, kernel, webcam

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. To my surprise, my webcam (Logitech c922 pro) is not detected by the kernel (5.4.0-29-generic). The same camera is however plug and play in 18.04 and works like a breeze

hwinfo --usb output :

```
21: USB 00.2: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: 4ajv.lVLMBtrsHd4
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2
  SysFS BusID: 1-1:1.2
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Logitech Unifying Receiver"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x046d "Logitech, Inc."
  Device: usb 0xc52b "Unifying Receiver"
  Revision: "12.11"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v046DpC52Bd1211dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in02"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: usbhid is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe usbhid"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #17 (Hub)
```

Also, note that there is no entry named `/dev/video*`

I tried running `sudo modprobe usbhid` but it returns no output and nothing happens

Please suggest a workaround.
Thanks

Comment: Please file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Logitech QuickCam Chat 046d:092e. I gave my user the right to use video devices, logged off and on again, and then it runs. I tested the cam with guvcview.